# Can available json response be reused in tritium to paint new mobile home page?

Tags: moovweb, tritium

I am trying to use moovweb to transform existing desktop site to mobile version. I already have so many ajax response available in the desktop version. We also have a new wire frame for the mobile version.Is there any way to reuse the ajax response and dynamically paint the page as per the new wireframe [by making use of tritium]?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information?

Comment: Yes Gregory! Thank you for your time. say, I have an OK button on my page. On click of this button ,an ajax is triggered.The response of this ajax [say-"data"] is used to paint some divs on the page. Will I have a handle on this "data" from tritium scripts?

Comment: @gregorygtseng [tag for the previous comment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tritium runs during the resource request/response scope, not on the javascript run time.

If you just want the exact same javascript behavior you currently have on desktop running on the mobile site, you already have that without doing anything - it will be "inherited".

However, if you want to change the behavior of the ajax callback, you will have to prevent the desktop script from running and recreate it with the different behavior on your mobile (moovweb) site.